# PHP: Running a shell command from PHP?

Tags: php, linux

```
echo shell_exec("ll");
```

Why doesn't php show me a list of files and directories when I run this code?

Comment: So what does it output for you?

Comment: In addition to the correct answers below (you are trying to exec an alias), make sure your host allows you to execute server-side commands.

Comment: Hi user, I thought this was an interesting question, but I don't think it will get a lot of upvotes without some more info. Consider an [edit] to add more details, like the output you were getting when you ran this command and if there were others you tried that worked. IMHO, this would make this a more upvote-worthy post that will help future visitors too! Good luck! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ll` isn't the command. I believe that `echo shell_exec("ls");` will output a list of directories.

Also you can have some problems if you are running PHP in safe mode. Here you have more information: http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

> `shell_exec`: This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

Eventually, you have more *secure* alternatives to execute a command in a bash like `readdir`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php. This is a function that read the files that are in a certain directory.

`readdir($dir_handle)`example:

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('/path/to/files')) {
    echo "Directory handle: $handle\n";
    echo "Entries:\n";

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5):

You're using an aliased command. That's why. What happens when you run `ls`?

Source: [PHP page for shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.shell-exec.php) and experience

Answer (score 5):

ll is often added as a default alias in bash (in your .bashrc file).

To double check whether ot not this is the case, type the following in your terminal:

```
type -a ll
```

Your shell will tell you whether or not ll is an alias or an actual program.

PHP runs in a different environment which does not have your default aliases installed.

The command expression you probably want is:

```
shell_exec("ls -l");
```